# va_list not working properly

Tags: variadic-functions

I have written a code:

```
 void xy(int a,...)
    {
    va_list list;
    va_start(list,a);
    int result=0;//va_start(list,x);

    for(;;)
    {
            int p=va_arg(list,int);
             cout<<p<<endl;
            if(p==0)
            break;

            result+=p;
    }

    va_end(list);
    cout<<result<<endl;
  }
```

and called this function :
     xy(20,30,40);

I am expecting 20, 30, 40 will be printed. and their sum. but it is printing :

30
40
13336564
11872144
-3271312
-3271224
12029596
11926688
134527888
-3271224
12029596
1
-3271180
-3271172
11929640
0
191296075

don't know why.

Please suggest some solution.

Comment: How to do that?? 
And why 20 is not being printed, why it's being started from 2nd parameter?? should i access it directly from variable a in xy function??

Answer (score 1):

Well, your code is really clever, isn't it? You are checking for a zero to mark the end of the parameter list. However, you are calling the function with a parameter list that doesn't end with or contain a zero. Where do you think would the zero come from that you are checking? Call instead

```
xy (20, 30, 40, 0);
```

bluebell's comment is obviously nonsense. THERE IS NO WAY TO DETECT THAT THERE ARE NO MORE ARGUMENTS. Caller and callee have to agree how to detect the end of the argument list, and then of course the caller has to send the write parameters.

printf does this by the caller sending a format string that the printf function will examine. Or you could send the number of arguments as the first parameter, so a function calculating the average of n values could be called as

```
average (1, 3.7);
average (3, 3.7, 4.1, 4.2);
```

20 is not printed because 20 is sent as the named argument, so your sum should start with the value a. 30 and 40 are received through the va_arg macro, as will be the number 0 if you pass it as a parameter - if you don't pass that number, your code will continue reading data from random memory locations until by chance it reads memory containing a number 0.

As another example: When you call printf ("%d %d\n", 4, 5); the printf function gets the format string "%d %d\n" as the first parameter. It examines this string and finds the letters %d twice, so it means there must be two int parameters. If you didn't supply two int parameters, you would expect rubbish to be printed.

Comment: I deleted my comment, sorry if that's bothering you and everyone else here. But actually, I didn't specify that you are to use standard library function to detect that there are no more arguments. I just said that you should exit the loop when there are no more arguments, and how that's implemented is left to the asker.

Comment: I have solved it by sending a NULL parameter through the function, and conditionally terminated the loop